# EF Core Creating relationships without querying them

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am wondering if there is a way to improve creation of relationships with EF Core, in sense of not having to query the item and then link it to related entity.

Example to better illustrate my point:

Assume two entities:

```
class Garage {
    int Id {get;set;}
    List<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}
class Car {
    string Name {get;set;}
    Garage Garage {get;set;}
}
```

Lets now assume a new Car is created and you want to link it to Garage of Id 1.

```
var garage = await context.Garage.FindAsync(1);
// sanity check the responses
var newCar = new Car {
  Name = 'Honda',
  Garage = garage
}

await context.AddAsync(car);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Is there a way to avoid retrieving the garage object, and instead implicitly specify it as Car relationship?

Essentially avoid making multiple calls to DB, do everything in one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Foreign Key property. You need to add the primary key of `Garage` into `Car` entity:

```cs
public class Garage
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Garage Garage { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Garage")]
  public int GarageId { get; set; } // <-- This is Foreign Key property
}
```

Then you need just to set that key (wherever it comes from):

```cs
var id = GetIdOfGarage(); // <-- Define id of Garage
var newCar = new Car
{
  Name = "Honda",
  GarageId = id
};
await context.AddAsync(newCar);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, sometimes the simplest solutions evade us. :)